# Java Lambdas : How it works in JVM & is it OOP?

Tags: java, oop, lambda, jvm, java-8

For example in the case of an anonymous inner class, an (anonymous) object reference is passed and methods of that object are executed.

Lambdas are code blocks which will be executed when needed.

What happens in the JVM when lambdas are encountered? Where does the JVM store the code blocks related to lambdas (Heap : Young, Old or Permanent Generation)?

I tried searching, and I got the syntax for using lambdas but was not able to understand what is happening inside JVM, as in JAVA everything is object-based.

1. So in context of OOP how do lambdas work?
2. Do lambdas violate OOP concepts?
3. Is Lambda good for the garbage collector as no objects are created hence
   no worry about memory issues and clearing memory?

Comment: I think lambdas are an other way to write your code more compact (or maybe better). 

The paradigm of OOP is not touched in that way, but thats my opinion.

Comment: Lambdas are important part of _functional programming_ which is different as you know from OOP.

Comment: On the face of it, lambda notation appears to violate some of the precepts of "structured programming", which is a (rarely mentioned) foundation of OOP.  I've not studied it close enough to elaborate, though, and *javac* has become one large unstructured mess over the past 10 years anyway.

Comment: If we're worrying about how lambdas are implemented in the compiler, or in the virtual machine, shouldn't someone do something about all those gotos first?

Comment: It doesn't matter if lambdas violate OOP as long as they help you write better code.

Comment: A common misconception is that OOP and FP are somehow at odds with each other.  But we don't get paid to write object-oriented programs or functional programs, we get paid to write *working* programs (ideally, anyway.)  Both OOP and FP offer us tools for containing the natural complexity of programming; as programmers, we should learn as much as we can from both OOP and FP, and use what each of them teaches where it helps to achieve the goal of writing working, maintainable, testable, readable, error-free programs.

Comment: No program is purely object oriented, no program is purely functional, no program is fully imperative. Programs are usually syncretic, mixing various concepts. For example oop is great for modeling complex business domain, while fp shines in areas like parallel or stream processing (filter, map, reduce, etc)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I wouldn't waste my time thinking whether the lambda expressions are a violation of OO principles. Its goal is to increase the power of a language and not to write an OO code, I don't see how lambdas can violate encapsulation, inheritance or polymorphism.

This [article](http://blog.takipi.com/compiling-lambda-expressions-scala-vs-java-8/) explains how Java handles lambda expressions:

> What’s interesting about Lambda expressions is that from the JVM’s perspective they’re completely invisible. It has no notion of what an anonymous function or a Lambda expression is. It only knows bytecode which is a strict OO specification. It’s up to the makers of the language and its compiler to work within these constraints to create newer, more advanced language elements.

Considering the following code:

```
List names = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
Stream lengths = names.stream().map(name -> name.length());
```

> ... It begins quite simply by loading the names var and invokes its `.stream()` method, but then it does something quite elegant. Instead of creating a new object that will wrap the Lambda function, it uses the new `invokeDynamic` instruction which was added in Java 7 to dynamically link this call site to the actual Lambda function.

```
aload_1 //load the names var

// call its stream() func
invokeinterface java/util/List.stream:()Ljava/util/stream/Stream;

//invokeDynamic magic!
invokedynamic #0:apply:()Ljava/util/function/Function;

//call the map() func
invokeinterface java/util/stream/Stream.map:
(Ljava/util/function/Function;)Ljava/util/stream/Stream;
```

> `InvokeDynamic` is an instruction that was added in Java 7 to make the JVM less strict, and allows dynamic languages to bind symbols at run-time, vs. doing all the linkage statically when the code is compiled by the JVM.

The Lambda code

```
aload_0
invokevirtual java/lang/String.length:()
invokestatic java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
areturn
```

Comment: It's not an answer. It's "hey, it uses invokedynamic, go and google it".

Comment: It's actually an answer, which is why the OP accepted it.

Answer (score 18):

Lambda expressions don't get translated into `anonymous inner classes`, they use [invoke dynamic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/multiple-language-support.html) that was introduced in Java 7 to execute functional methods. [Check this out](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Java-8-Lambdas-A-Peek-Under-the-Hood).

Do they violate `OOP`? I don't think that you should care. Lambdas make your code less verbose, easier to understand, and "easier" to parallelise. And thats what you should care about.

From Brain Goetz comment:

> We don't get paid to write object-oriented programs or functional programs, we get paid to write working programs.

Comment: Afaik lambdas do get translated to anonymous inner classes in *some* cases. But that happens at runtime by the invokedynamic bootstrap handler that figures out the best strategy to handle a particular lambda.

Comment: @the8472 To the tiny extent that this statement might be viewable as correct in an angels-on-the-head-of-a-pin sense, it's still a negatively helpful characterization.  You are far better off just letting go of any connection to inner classes -- it will lead to a better understanding.

Comment: @BrianGoetz, it wasn't really supposed to be a characterization of lambdas, more a nitpick about implementation details.

Comment: @the8472: it’s a *class* that might be generated and it actually happens to be called “inner class” even in the factory, however, it lacks every aspect of an ordinary inner class that makes it distinct from top level classes, neither the “inner” nor the “outer” class contain any information about an inner class relationship.

Comment: Ah, I see. I think I got confused by the innerClass stuff in the lambda factory + the synthetic methods that appear in the call stacks. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

- Lambda expression is compiled using `invokedynamic` bytecode.
- Lambda implementation is stored in the same class file as a special private method.
- Whether an object is created to invoke lambda depends on the situation. In the trivial cases lambda gets translated to a constant method handle.
- To instantiate a lambda HotSpot creates an anonymous class that implements lambda's functional interface. This class does not belong to any ClassLoader.

See [more details](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-translation.html) from the specification lead of [Lambda Expressions JSR](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=335).